# access nested fields in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i defined two schemas one is user and one is doc.
in doc schema i use createdBy field to reference user schema

now when i want to display all record in doc schema i am not able to access the name

i can access doc.education or doc.bio but not able to access the perticular doc name

here is what i have tried

```
  doc
    .find({})
    .populate({ path: "createdBy" })
    .exec((err, docs) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(docs);
      }
    });
```

i get this result

```
[
  {
    _id: 5efa9ab935f13d39b01f36e2,
    createdBy: {
      role: 'doctor',
      isVerified: false,
      _id: 5ef873fe544ef53874eaacfe,
      name: 'drsmira',
      email: 'drsmira@gmail.com',
      password: '$2a$10$X/52qRFCYA/DwZ6Z1ZftVu2gv.MJ4HsqXrRuB8.ZLbqj.4EVtVmBG',
      select: 'Female',
      date: 2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z,
      phone: '342343',
      city: 'dff',
      state: 'dfss',
      specifications: [],
      __v: 0
    },
    bio: 'wweqeqwe',
    speciality: 'dentist',
    education: 'mbbs',
    treatment: 'oral care',
    location: 'ewrewre',
    hospitalList: 'sahyadri',
    awards: 'ererewrwe',
    fee: '888',
    __v: 0,
    achievements: ''
  }
]
```

now i want to access name field. how do i do this

i itried implementing

```
console.log(docs.createdBy.name)
```

but returns undefined

Comment: docs is an `array` so you need to either iterate the array or `console.log(docs[0].createdBy.name)` to get first element in array

Comment: still it shows ---- Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

so i did little digging and thanks to the comment of vishnu

i used forEach loop to get the result

below is the updated code

```
doc
    .find({})
    .populate({ path: "createdBy" })
    .exec((err, docs) => {
      if (!err) {
        docs.forEach((el) => {
          console.log(el.createdBy.name);
        });
        res.render("doctors", { list: docs });
      }
    });
```